# Get the instance of Activity from the Child Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

My activity extends `AppCompatActivity`, and I started a `Fragment` there with support library fragment manager:

```
    public MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        ...

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
          super.onResume();
          // show my fragment
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, myFragment, TAG).commit();
        }
    }
```

**My question is**, in `MyFragment`, how can I get the instance of `MyActivity` who started it?

```
//NOTE: it extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // How to get the instance of MyActivity here?
        // I tried: getActivity() but it returns FragmentActivity 
       //& MyActivity is AppCompatActivity
    }
}
```

I know there is `getActivity()` function in `Fragment`, but it returns `FragmentActivity`:
[image]

Comment: Why downvoting?

Comment: You can cast it `((MyActivity)getActivity())` - but you shouldn't. Instead, use [Communicating with other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: Call `getActivity()` within [Fragment#onActivityCreated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)) then cast it to the specific Activity.

Comment: But getActivity() returns FragmentActivity, mine is AppCompatActivity, would cast work?

Comment: AppCompatActivity extends to FragmentActivity so it should work.

Comment: Your `Fragment` doesn't (and shouldn't) know that it is attached to an `AppCompatActivity`, but you do, which is why the cast works. This is also why casting in this way is a bad idea, as it tightly couples the Fragment to its Activity implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
((MyActivity) getActivity()).
```

then access anything from activity class

Comment: But getActivity() returns FragmentActivity, mine is AppCompatActivity, are you saying FragmentActivity is a child of AppCompatActivity?

Comment: Yes... As you can see here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html

Comment: http://madhusudhanrc.blogspot.in/2012/09/android-objective-type-question-and.html

Comment: Please go through this

Comment: For any case, getActivity always return the "parent" activity (when not null).. Since your fragment was started by MyActivity, you will get an instance of MyActivity.. so, you can cast.